# Python Figure not responding after I ask for input?

Tags: python, loops, input

So the following is a snippet of what I'm working on where I'm working on and it's meant to find the peaks from the data. I'm trying to add user choice into the mix and for each peak whether it's good or not. I want to have the figure constantly change throughout the script and the input will save the peak value for later use. But the figure simply doesn't respond and I can't seem to find why. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import os 
import numpy as np
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for moving in range(len(indexes)):
    parsedFile = 'TEST/parsedWVIAdata_%d-%d_%d' % (DT[1,0],int(DT[1,5]),moving + 1)

    plt.figure(1)    
    plt.plot(HD,H2O)
    plt.plot(HD[indexes[moving]],H2O[indexes[moving]],"rx")
    plt.axis([HD[indexes[moving]]-xrang,HD[indexes[moving]]+xrang,H2O[indexes[moving]]-yrang,H2O[indexes[moving]]+yrang])
    plt.show()

    select = False
    rawrchoice = raw_input("Is this point a peak (y/n): ")
    if rawrchoice=='y': select = True
    peaks = 4

    plt.savefig(parsedFile+'.jpg',pdi=1000)
    plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

Picture of figure not responding - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnk2X.png

Comment: Where is `DT` defined ? and `indexes` ?

Comment: `DT` is an array of values but `DT[1,0]` is `2016.0` and `int(DT[1,5])` is `108`. Most of the undeclared values that I didn't mention are just values or a list

Comment: You don't provide us something debuggable - so it's impossible for us to help you. Start by debugging your code - see which line fails - that should give you a good idea where to start digging.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still a novice but what would qualify as debuggable? should I have attached the data file and where my values were defined?

Comment: It means that either provide us with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so we'll be able to reproduce, or alternatively, debug your code, see which line fails and start digging there. In case you don't use [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) - I highly recommend that you'll start using it, it's very easy to debug with it.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the scrub question and I appreciate the response.